# where will I will get mysql 5.6 developer certification exam model paper

Tags: mysql

where will I get **Oracle Mysql 5.6 Developer exam 1z0-882** sample questions
   which is so beneficial for this exam.
                     Thanks Friends in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog entry from Oracle's Todd Farmer should help

http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2013/10/15/exam-cram-preparing-for-the-mysql-5-6-certification-exams/

Has has provided some practice sections in the linked articles under ("Index")